# Composition of Gysin and restriction maps on $\ell$-adic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, projective-varieties, poincare-duality

I already posted this question on mathstackexchange [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739910/composition-of-gysin-and-restriction-maps-on-ell-adic-cohomology), but I figured that it may have more replies here.

---

I follow the notations of Milne's lectures notes on etale cohomology, most specifically the section titled "The Gysin map" in chapter 24, p. 145.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, let $Y$ and $X$ be two non singular (separated) complete varieties of respective dimensions $d$ and $a$, and let $\pi: Y\hookrightarrow X$ be a closed immersion. In particular $a \geq d$ and let $c := a - d$ denote the codimension. Let $\Lambda = \mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$ for some $n$ which is prime with the characteristic of $k$. Since the varieties are complete, I do not bother to distinguish between cohomology with or without compact support.

Functoriality of etale cohomology provides us with restriction maps $\pi^*: \mathrm H^r(X,\Lambda) \to \mathrm H^r(Y,\Lambda)$. Taking duals and applying Poincaré duality as well as some Tate twist, we obtain maps $\pi_*:\mathrm H^r(Y,\Lambda) \to \mathrm H^{r+2c}(X,\Lambda(c))$. These are the Gysin maps.

Let $1_Y$ denote the identity element of $\mathrm H^0(Y,\Lambda) \simeq \Lambda$. The element $\pi_*(1_Y) \in \mathrm H^{2c}(X,\Lambda(c))$ is, by definition, the image of $Y$, seen as a prime cycle on $X$, via the cycle map $\mathrm{cl}_X: \mathrm{CH}^c(X)\to \mathrm H^{2c}(X,\Lambda(c))$.

In Remark 24.2, Milne states the projection formula. As a particular case, for any $x\in \mathrm H^r(X,\Lambda)$, we have the identity
$$\pi_*\pi^*(x) = \mathrm{cl}_X(Y) \cup x \in \mathrm H^{r+2c}(X,\Lambda(c)).$$
(Simply take $y = 1_Y \in \mathrm H^0(Y,\Lambda)$ in Milne's notations).

Thus, we have an explicit formula to describe $\pi_*\pi^*: \mathrm H^r(X,\Lambda) \to \mathrm H^{r+2c}(X,\Lambda(c))$.

Is there similarly a formula to compute the reverse composition, ie. $\pi^*\pi_*: \mathrm H^r(Y,\Lambda) \to \mathrm H^{r+2c}(Y,\Lambda(c))$? Would this map be similarly described as a cup product by some canonically defined element of the cohomology of $Y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: $\pi ^*\pi _*$ is the cup-product with $c_c(N)$, the $c$-th Chern class of the normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$. This is Theorem VII.4.1 in SGA 5.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the precise reference, I appreciate it! However, I was unable to find "Theorem 4.1" in Exposé VII of SGA 6. Unless I'm mistaken, number 4.1 seems to refer to an (unrelated?) Lemma. Maybe the correct reference is Proposition 2.7?

Comment: I am sorry, this is an awful typo, I meant SGA 5! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you again